# extreme beginner to python, cant understand an error

Tags: python

super new to python and having an error on one of my codecademy projects that i cant seem to understand, even referencing the walkthrough and altering line 17 multiple times i cant quiet understand why this is returning an error. could somebody help me understand the error so i can learn from it? this is my code thats returning a type error:

````
lovely_loveseat_description = """Lovely Loveseat. Tufted polyester blend on wood. 32 inches high X 40 inches wide X 30 inches deep. Available in Red or White."""
lovely_loveseat_price = 254.00
stylish_setee_description = """Stylish Settee. Faux leather on birch.
29.50 inches high X 54.75 inches wide X 28 inches deep. Available only in Black."""
stylish_settee_price = 150.50
luxurious_lamp_description = "Luxurious Lamp. Glass and iron. 36 inches tall. Available in Brown with a Stylish Beige shade."
luxurious_lamp_price = 52.15
#sales tax variable.
sales_tax = .088
#base shopping cart total value.
customer_one_total = 0
#shopping cart contents variable.
customer_one_itemization = ""
#shopping area.
customer_one_total =+ lovely_loveseat_price
customer_one_itemization =+ lovely_loveseat_description
customer_one_total =+ luxurious_lamp_price
customer_one_itemization =+ luxurious_lamp_description
customer_one_tax = customer_one_total * sales_tax
customer_one_total =+ customer_one_tax
print("Customer One Items:")
print(customer_one_itemization)
print("Customer One Total Cost:")
print(customer_one_total)```


and this is the error:
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 17, in <module>
    customer_one_itemization =+ lovely_loveseat_description
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'```

thanks heaps guys.
````

Comment: `+=`, not `=+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `=+` operator should be `+=`;

Comment: `=+` is not an operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = "hello"
>>> b = "bye"
>>> a =+ b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
>>> a += b
>>> a
'hellobye'
```

Cannot do `=+` like that on strings

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is `+=` not `=+`

```py
lovely_loveseat_description = """Lovely Loveseat. Tufted polyester blend on wood. 32 inches high X 40 inches wide X 30 inches deep. Available in Red or White."""
lovely_loveseat_price = 254.00
stylish_setee_description = """Stylish Settee. Faux leather on birch.
29.50 inches high X 54.75 inches wide X 28 inches deep. Available only in Black."""
stylish_settee_price = 150.50
luxurious_lamp_description = "Luxurious Lamp. Glass and iron. 36 inches tall. Available in Brown with a Stylish Beige shade."
luxurious_lamp_price = 52.15
#sales tax variable.
sales_tax = .088
#base shopping cart total value.
customer_one_total = 0
#shopping cart contents variable.
customer_one_itemization = ""
#shopping area.
customer_one_total += lovely_loveseat_price
customer_one_itemization += lovely_loveseat_description
customer_one_total += luxurious_lamp_price
customer_one_itemization += luxurious_lamp_description
customer_one_tax = customer_one_total * sales_tax
customer_one_total += customer_one_tax
print("Customer One Items:")
print(customer_one_itemization)
print("Customer One Total Cost:")
print(customer_one_total)
```